# .NET Framework 4 - First Entity Framework call to database never completes in console application

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0

So I have two applications, an ASP.NET Web Forms application (same framework) and a console application (same framework) that leverages a business logic library. On the Web Forms application, everything runs great as far as performance goes. On the console application, it hangs on the first entity framework call to the SQL Server instance.

From the User class that is the various properties of the table that are used by the DbSet:

```
 public static List<User> GetUsersWithPrefixesOrProdLines()
{
  LegacyContext db = new LegacyContext();
  var records = db.Users.Where(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Proto_Prefixes) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Product_Lines)).ToList(); // hangs here
  return records;
}
```

There's nothing particularly special about this table. There are about 50 records of 8 columns of data. I can run this from the WebForms application incredibly quickly. The console application unfortunately has been running for 10 minutes and it hasn't spit out the result of

```
 List<User> users = User.GetUsersWithPrefixesOrProdLines();
 Console.WriteLine("Users Count: " + users.Count());
```

Comment: var connectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString; // assuming EF6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a database connection issue. I would check the Connection String in the console app.config (and resulting .exe.config file) which will depend on what database you are using and authentication mode. (I.e. SQL Server account or integrated, etc.) For instance if your connection string is using an integrated mode, the windows account used for the website app pool may have access to the database while the account running the console app does not. If the console app is being run automatically like with a scheduler, look at what user account it is being run as.

One important detail about working with EF DbContexts is that they should always be disposed on use:

```
public static List<User> GetUsersWithPrefixesOrProdLines()
{
    using (LegacyContext db = new LegacyContext())
    {
        var records = db.Users
            .Where(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Proto_Prefixes) 
               || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Product_Lines))
            .ToList(); 
        return records;
    }
}
```

Leaving DbContexts open will lead to memory leaks and other potential issues. Disposing the DbContext /w a `using` block might lead to unexpected errors if your code is relying on lazy loading outside the scope of this method. (I.e. User references other entities and the caller of this method accesses those navigation properties) With an undisposed DbContext the lazy load calls would work, but disposing the DbContext to release it would cause those to fail. Either eager load the related entities or move the scope of the DbContext outside of this method. (I.e. module level and not a static method or passing the DbContext into the method as an argument) You can inspect the connection string actually used at runtime with:

```
var connectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString; // assuming EF6
```

Comment: It's even worse than that from a doh standpoint, but same area: VPN dropped so I couldn't access the database server. Moral of the story: the issue veers towards connection issues as you said.